Некорректная работа maven-javadoc-plugin с hibernate-jpamodelgen
Я столкнулся с проблемой, что получаю ошибку:
Exit code: 1
C:\Users\*\Desktop\*\*\*\target\delombok\ru\*\*\service\impl\*.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
import ru.*.*.entity.Balance_;
                                     ^
  symbol:   class Balance_
  location: package ru.*.*.entity
1 error
Command line was: cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\javadoc.exe" @options @argfile"

Refer to the generated Javadoc files in 'C:\Users\*\Desktop\*\repositories\*\target\apidocs' dir.

и вот описание того, как воспроизвести данную проблему:

Добавляем codegen зависимости

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.32</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.4.Final</version>
</dependency>


Добавляем плагины maven-javadoc-plugin и maven-compiler-plugin (чтобы добавить ему annotationProcessorPaths)

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                <version>6.4.4.Final</version>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.32</version>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                <version>0.2.0</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
        <compilerArgs>
            <compilerArg>
                -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
            </compilerArg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>


Всё. Далее в любом месте в коде используем эти модели. Например, просто выведем в лог поле статической модели log.info(String.valueOf(Balance_.id)); и при попытке сделать mvn clean package будет получена ошибка. Что не так я делаю?


import ru.*.*.entity.Balance_; так не работает. Нужно писать полное название пакета.

блин чел.... ты... ну это рабочий проект) скрыл я название пакета своего. это вообще ни на что не влияет

А "Note: Hibernate compile-time tooling 6.5.2.Final" в консоль пишет? Если нет, значит процессор не запускается.

Проблема может быть вызвана многими факторами, связанными с генерацией метамоделей JPA (классы, заканчивающиеся на _ ), которую выполняет hibernate-jpamodelgen. Ошибка cannot find symbol для класса Balance_ говорит о том, что он не был сгенерирован должным образом. Покажите более детальный лог: mvn clean package -X
